# remove B elements add them at the end of the doment load

Tags: jquery, textnode

I have an issue with a jquery script using text node to find and wrap text in a div.

It's ignoring `<b>` elements at the very start. But not after any plain text.

```
<b>Bold introduction</b>
content content content <b>content</b> content
```

To this:

```
<b>Bold introduction</b>

<div class="description">
content content content <b>content</b> content

</div>
```

One solution I can think of is to remove `<b>` elments and then reinsert them after the text node script has fired. Is the possible? Thanks

EDIT: sorry wasn't clear. The above is what I want to fix. Ie:

```
<div class="description">
<b>Bold introduction</b>
content content content <b>content</b> content

</div>
```

Here is the text node script jsfiddle with the error
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pZvS/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn this:

```
<b>Bold introduction</b>
content content content <b>content</b> content
```

into this:

```
<b>Bold introduction</b>

<div class="description">
content content content <b>content</b> content

</div>
```

I think you want

```
$("b:first").nextAll().wrapAll("<div class='description' />");
```

**EDIT**

If you want to *move* these elements into the description div, then this should do that

```
var toMove = $("b:first").nextAll().remove();
$(".description").append(toMove);
```

Comment: Could I `.append` that to the div?

Comment: @uriah - probably - I'm not sure what you mean.  The code above takes everything after the first <b>, and wraps them in a div of class'description' -- is that not what you want?

Comment: nah, I wanted to move it into the `.description` after the `.description` has been made. Sorry